# nginx ip address not redirecting to domain

Tags: nginx, https, http, 301-redirect

I have set up a http -> https redirect like so, however, it is not redirecting `http://ipaddress:5000` to `https://subdomain.mydomain.com`

```
    # HTTP — redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    return 301 https://subdomain.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name subdomain.mydomain.com;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doen't listen to port 5000. I guess you should fix your application to use main host instead of ip:port

Comment: is there any way to forward port 5000 requests to the domain? or to allow port 5000 requests through as normal until I can communicate the change

Comment: It's your application listens to port 5000. Nginx has nothing to do with it. Once again, just configure you application properly. If you tell us what is you app is based on (php/wordpress, python/jango, nodejs/express, whatever else) may be we could point you to right direction.

Comment: ah okay, fair enough. It's a node/express app. thanks